# Print newline with as little code as possible with NASM

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, nasm, code-size

I'm learning a bit of assembly for fun and I am probably too green to know the right terminology and find the answer myself.

I want to print a newline at the end of my program.

Below works fine.

```
section .data
    newline db 10

section  .text
_end:
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, newline
    mov rdx, 1
    syscall

    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall
```

But I'm hoping to achieve the same result without defining the newline in .data. Is it possible to call `sys_write` directly with the byte you want, or must it always be done with a reference to some predefined data (which I assume is what `mov rsi, newline` is doing)?

In short, why can't I replace `mov rsi, newline` by `mov rsi, 10`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *always* need the data in memory to copy it to a file-descriptor.  **There is no system-call equivalent of C stdio `fputc` that takes data by value instead of by pointer.**

`mov rsi, newline` puts a *pointer* into a register (with a huge `mov r64, imm64` instruction).  `sys_write` doesn't special-case size=1 and treat its `void *buf` arg as a char *value* if it's not a valid pointer.

There aren't any other system calls that would do the trick.  `pwrite` and `writev` are both *more* complicated (taking a file offset as well as a pointer, or taking an array of pointer+length to gather the data in kernel space).

---

**There is a *lot* you can do to optimize this for code-size, though.**  See https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132981/tips-for-golfing-in-x86-x64-machine-code

First, putting the newline character in static storage means you need to generate a static address in a register.  Your options here are:

- 5-bytes `mov esi, imm32`  (only in Linux non-PIE executables, so static addresses are link-time constants and are known to be in the low 2GiB of virtual address space and thus work as 32-bit zero-extended or sign-extended)
- 7-byte `lea rsi, [rel newline]` Works everywhere, the only good option if you can't use the 5-byte mov-immediate.
- 10-byte `mov rsi, imm64`.  This works even in PIE executables (e.g. if you link with `gcc -nostdlib` without `-static`, on a distro where PIE is the default.)  But only via a runtime relocation fixup, and the code-size is terrible.  Compilers never use this because it's not faster than LEA.

---

But like I said, **we can avoid static addressing entirely: Use `push` to put immediate data on the stack**.  This works even if we need zero-terminated strings, because `push imm8` and `push imm32` both sign-extend the immediate to 64-bit.  Since ASCII uses the low half of the 0..255 range, this is equivalent to zero-extension.

Then we just need to copy RSP to RSI, because `push` leave RSP pointing to the data that was pushed.  `mov rsi, rsp` would be 3 bytes because it needs a REX prefix.  If you were targeting 32-bit code or the x32 ABI (32-bit pointers in long mode) you could use 2-byte `mov esi, esp`.  But Linux puts the stack pointer at top of user virtual address space, so on x86-64 that's 0x007ff..., right at the top of the low canonical range.  So truncating a pointer to stack memory to 32 bits isn't an option; we'd get `-EFAULT`.

But we can copy a 64-bit register with 1-byte `push` + 1-byte `pop`.  (Assuming neither register needs a REX prefix to access.)

```
default rel     ; We don't use any explicit addressing modes, but no reason to leave this out.

_start:
    push   10         ; \n

    push   rsp
    pop    rsi        ; 2 bytes total vs. 3 for mov rsi,rsp

    push   1          ; _NR_write call number
    pop    rax        ; 3 bytes, vs. 5 for mov edi, 1

    mov    edx, eax   ; length = call number by coincidence
    mov    edi, eax   ; fd = length = call number  also coincidence
    syscall           ;   write(1, "\n", 1)

    mov    al, 60     ; assuming write didn't return -errno, replace the low byte and keep the high zeros
    ;xor    edi, edi    ; leave rdi = 1  from write
    syscall           ; _exit(1)

.size: db $ - _start
```

[xor-zeroing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and) is the most well-known x86 peephole optimization: it saves 3 bytes of code size, and is actually *more* efficient than `mov edi, 0`.  But you only asked for the smallest code to print a newline, without specifying that it had to exit with status = 0.  So we can save 2 bytes by leaving that out.

Since we're just making an `_exit` system call, we don't need to clean up the stack from the `10` we pushed.

BTW, this will crash if the `write` returns an error.  (e.g. redirected to `/dev/full`, or closed with `./newline >&-`, or whatever other condition.)  That would leave RAX=-something, so `mov al, 60` would give us RAX=`0xffff...3c`.  Then we'd get `-ENOSYS` from the invalid call number, and fall off the end of `_start` and decode whatever is next as instructions.  (Probably zero bytes which decode with `[rax]` as an addressing mode.  Then we'd fault with a SIGSEGV.)

---

`objdump -d -Mintel` disassembly of that code, after building with `nasm -felf64` and linking with `ld`

```
0000000000401000 <_start>:
  401000:       6a 0a                   push   0xa
  401002:       54                      push   rsp
  401003:       5e                      pop    rsi
  401004:       6a 01                   push   0x1
  401006:       58                      pop    rax
  401007:       89 c2                   mov    edx,eax
  401009:       89 c7                   mov    edi,eax
  40100b:       0f 05                   syscall 
  40100d:       b0 3c                   mov    al,0x3c
  40100f:       0f 05                   syscall 

0000000000401011 <_start.size>:
  401011:       11                      .byte 0x11
```

**So the total code-size is 0x11 = 17 bytes.  vs. your version with 39 bytes of code + 1 byte of static data**.  Your first 3 `mov` instructions alone are 5, 5, and 10 bytes long.  (Or 7 bytes long for `mov rax,1` if you use YASM which doesn't optimize it to `mov eax,1`).

Running it:

```
$ strace ./newline 
execve("./newline", ["./newline"], 0x7ffd4e98d3f0 /* 54 vars */) = 0
write(1, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
exit(1)                                 = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

---

#### If this was part of a larger program:

If you already have a pointer to some nearby static data in a register, you could do something like a 4-byte `lea rsi, [rdx + newline-foo]` (REX.W + opcode + modrm + disp8), assuming the `newline-foo` offset fits in a sign-extended disp8 and that RDX holds the address of `foo`.

Then you can have `newline: db 10` in static storage after all.  (Put it `.rodata` or `.data`, depending on which section you already had a pointer to).

Comment: Nitpicking: "Compilers never use this" - in the default memory model. `gcc -mcmodel=large` will use it.

Answer (score 2):

It expects an address of the string in `rsi` register. Not a character or string.

`mov rsi, newline` loads the address of `newline` into `rsi`.

Comment: so it must always be an address and therefore defined in memory. There's no way to give it the required value straight up?

Comment: @bluppfisk , correct. I'm not an expert in Linux syscalls API, but I doubt that there is another write syscall with direct value.

Comment: @Renat: yes, to my knowledge, there aren't any system calls that copy data to an FD or socket that take it by value like `putc` instead of by pointer+length like `write`/`fwrite`.  I'm not an expert in Linux system calls the way I am in x86 asm, but I don't see a use-case for it; system calls are expensive and totally dwarf the extra cost of a store or load in user-space for a 1-byte read or write.  It's not something the kernel would ever want to encourage.  There are system calls like `splice(2)` and `tee(2)` that copy data between FDs inside the kernel, avoiding copy to/from userspace...

Comment: I flipped through `asm/unistd_64.h` and there are some new ones like `preadv2` (takes flags where classic POSIX `preadv` doesn't).  Wow, since Linux 4.3 there's a [`userfaultfd(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/userfaultfd.2.html) that allows a user-space thread to handle page-faults for other threads in the process!  The ever-growing list of Linux system calls is always interesting.  But yeah, pretty sure still no read/write by value.

Comment: both answers are great and in essence it boils down to you cannot write by value, but in the end I went with Peter's for the sheer amount of information. Thanks both.